# Magento 2 multi website unable to set Developer mode "production"

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I am using magento 2 with multiple websites, need to enable production mode. But it getting error with _custom.less can't able to read my theme package.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating multi website in magento2 or further versions, you need to follow some basic points:

```
1. Di compilation
2. Symlinks for multi websites
```

assume that you already know how to access your Shell or SSH Access using Terminal (MAC) or Putty software.

Common problems on creating symlinks are usually caused by syntax error on command line-interface, incorrect file patch to the server, and incorrect commands.

If you can see this similar command line when browsing any tutorials via the internet like what you can see below

```
ln -s ../public_html/app ./app
```

This is actually an incorrect file path from the server.

ln the command line stands to creating links – files which “point” to other files or directories in the filesystem.

Thus, the command line should look like this

```
ln -s existingPath pointingtoExistingPath
```

existingPath literally means that this path or folder is existing and pointingtoExistingPath is the path in which your symlinks or symbolic links will be created.

So to be exact, your symlinks command will look like this

ln -s /home/username/public_html/app /home/username/public_html/Newstore/app
Username is usually the username you used when accessing your cPanel
Newstore folder and app subfolder will be automatically created when you provide a correct path.

To check if you are accessing the correct path, just type

```
ln /home/username/public_html/app
```

and you will get this similar message

“hard link not allowed for directory”
Finally we hopefully derived a correct command line/path

```
ln -s /home/username/public_html/app /home/username/public_html/Newstore/app
ln -s /home/username/public_html/lib /home/username/public_html/Newstore/lib

ln -s /home/username/public_html/pub /home/username/public_html/Newstore/pub
ln -s /home/username/public_html/var /home/username/public_html/Newstore/var
```